# Cygwin cannot find make program but it is installed

Tags: cygwin

I have installed Cygwin on a Windows 7 SP1 Professional 64 bits.

I've just added make to the installation, then I restarted the shell but it doesn't find it.

If I do `ls -la /bin/ma*` I get:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 Uic18 IC+Group(513)  92691 oct 10  2016 /bin/man.exe
-rwxr-xr-x 1 Uic18 IC+Group(513) 113683 oct 10  2016 /bin/mandb.exe
-rwxr-xr-x 1 Uic18 IC+Group(513)  29203 oct 10  2016 /bin/manpath.exe
```

But, If I do `ls -la /cygdrive/d/cygwin64/bin/ma*` I get:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 Uic18 IC+Group(513) 198675 abr  1  2017 /cygdrive/d/cygwin64/bin/make.exe
-rwxr-xr-x 1 Uic18 IC+Group(513)  92691 ene 23 21:23 /cygdrive/d/cygwin64/bin/man.exe
-rwxr-xr-x 1 Uic18 IC+Group(513) 113683 ene 23 21:23 /cygdrive/d/cygwin64/bin/mandb.exe
-rwxr-xr-x 1 Uic18 IC+Group(513)  29203 ene 23 21:23 /cygdrive/d/cygwin64/bin/manpath.exe
```

And `make` appears installed in the installer (`setup-x86_64.exe`).

Do I need to do something else?

Comment: Malwarebytes requires an exclusion for make, in case you have that.

Comment: `ls -la /usr/bin/ma*` can not produce `/bin/ma*` . You are missing the `/usr` so something is wrong on your description. Are you sure you have not used `/bin/man*` ?

Comment: @matzeri Yes, you are right, I made a mistake. I have fixed in the question.

Comment: @tim18 I don't have Malwarebytes installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have two separate installations of Cygwin installed.  When you did your `ls -la /bin/ma*`, you were in your first installation that does not have `make`, but your `ls -la /cygdrive/d/cygwin64/bin/ma*` is looking at the contents of the second installation installed under `D:\cygwin64\`.

(Note that the executables from installation #1 date back to 2016, while the executables for installation #2 date to January of this year.)

So, if you start your terminal/shell from the right place, you should be all right.  (If you're using a shortcut, e.g., make sure that it's referencing `D:\cygwin64\bin` and not something else.)

You can double-check your installation mounts by issuing `df -a` from your Cygwin terminal.

Comment: good catching of the different date. May be there is a 32bit and a 64bit installation